# Homography matrix computation

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I went through multiple resources and found that 4 pairs of points are required (4 points in source image and 4 points in destination image) to form homography transformation matrix. Why pair of 4 points are required to compute homography transformation and not 3? Or why specifically 4?

Comment: I'd look into a few lectures (such as [Image geometry and planar homography](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVJeJMWZcq8)). I wish I could point you to the direct answer. My hunch is it might have something to do with avoiding ambiguity: having a system of equations that results in a single valid solution as opposed to multiple solutions.

Comment: Does [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40289/why-do-we-need-4-points-for-homography-but-7-8-points-for-fundamental-matrix-cal) solve your question?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza and Grillteller thanks for sharing the resources, after going through both I understood that in a homography matrix there are 8 elements to be computed and a pair of points can be used to solve 2 constraints i.e. 2 unknowns, thus 4 pair of points are required for computing 8 unknown elements. Am I correct?